# Python Pandas Series Tuples dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have somehow got a Series with index as a Tuple where as data as a number. I want to convert it into a series with index as a single string that is by removing the tuple[0] value.[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAoa4.png) [Desired Output is something like this but in a series format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXUk7.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should probably include the data shown in the link in the question as to avoid dead links in the future

Comment: @Raz0rwire I am new to stackoverflow, not sure what you are suggesting. Are the links not working? Or do you want me to paste the data in the question itself. Will be helpful if you reply on this as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need select second value of tuples by `str[1]`:

```
s.index = s.index.str[1]
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series([80,79,70], 
              index=[('total','Mumbai'),('total','Chennai'),('total','Royal')])
print (s)
(total, Mumbai)     80
(total, Chennai)    79
(total, Royal)      70
dtype: int64

s.index = s.index.str[1]
print (s)
Mumbai     80
Chennai    79
Royal      70
dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
s.index = s.index.map(lambda x: x[1])
print (s)
Mumbai     80
Chennai    79
Royal      70
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I was not using the .str function